# Switching @import sass modules (files) in Vue (Vuex) to change color themes

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

I'm trying to get my head around the best approach to this (or if it's even possible). I have a rather large application i have set the color sass variables globally within two separated files - _theme-dark.scss and _theme-light.scss. Now i would like to allow the user to switch between the two say via a click of a button.

Here's an example of my app.scss file:

***app.scss***

```
@import 'modules/theme-dark';
//@import 'modules/theme-light';
```

FYI switch the code comments between the two files manually works, no i just need to make it dynamic.

Comment: A possible solution would be to create a `app_light.scss` and `app_dark.scss` importing the specifig theme file and then the `app.scss`. After this build both of them instead of the `app.scss` and switch the html style tag dynamically

Comment: Have you heard of [Themify](https://github.com/salesforce/themify)? It's a postcss plugin accomplishes what you're trying to do.